# map Array and conditionally style specific elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, jsx

**I have a list of appointment time that I am getting from the database, I want to check if the array below i.e time3 contains any appointment time then I disable that time on the client side , but the problem is when ı use conditionals in reactjs its disables all the times **

```
  const time3 = [
        ["08:00", "08:10", "08:20", "08:30", "08:40", "08:50"],
        ["09:00", "09:10", "09:20", "09:30", "09:40", "09:50"],
        ["10:00", "10:10", "10:20", "10:30", "10:40", "10:50"],
        ["11:00", "11:10", "11:20", "11:30", "11:40", "11:50"],
        ["12:00", "12:10", "12:20", "12:30", "12:40", "12:50"],
        ["13:00", "13:10", "13:20", "13:30", "13:40", "13:50"],
        ["14:00", "14:10", "14:20", "14:30", "14:40", "14:50"],
        ["15:00", "15:10", "15:20", "15:30", "15:40", "15:50"],
        ["16:00", "16:10", "16:20", "16:30", "16:40", "16:50"],
        ["17:00", "17:10", "17:20", "17:30", "17:40", "17:50"],
        ["18:00", "18:10", "18:20", "18:30", "18:40", "18:50"]

    ]

let timeArrayList = []
time3.map((timesArray) => {
    return timesArray.map((time) => {
        return timeArrayList.push(time)
    })
})
```

This is what I am rendering

```
{
    time3.map((time, i) => {
        return (
            <Panel header={time[0]}>
                {time.map((t, i) => {
                    return (
                        <>
                            <button
                                key={i}
                                value={t}
                                disabled={timeArrayList.includes(t) ? true : false}
                            >
                                {t}
                            </button>
                        </>
                    );
                })}
            </Panel>
        );
    });
}
```

All the array elements are being disabled can you help , I am also open to refactoring the code especially the array to make it muuch more easier for me to access the elements

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. 'timeArrayList' is a 1d-array that contains all the time slots in the 2d-array time3. Then you checked if the each individual time slot is in time3 (which of course it is) and based on that, the button is disabled. Which seems like it's what you're trying to accomplish. Isn't it?

Comment: Beacuse here you are converting 2D array to flat array, Mapping elements from 2D array and checking is it there in flat array. Its there since you pushed to timeArrayList array. You need to have array of timeSlot and bookedSlot. Else above metioned output is expected.